# Replace last occurrence of word between 2 words with RegEx

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm working with RegEx on Java and here is where I stuck.

I have a simple string like

```
String sample1 = "word 231 sadas aslkjasf anything ORDER what whut ASC hello ORDER whatever."
```

I have to find every substring until the last occurrence of `ASC` between two `ORDER`s and replace them with word `QQQ`.

Here are some examples:

```
String sample1 = "word 231 sadas aslkjasf anything ORDER what whut ASC hello ORDER whatever.";
String result1 = "word 231 sadas aslkjasf anything QQQ hello ORDER whatever.";
// replaced "ORDER what whut ASC"

String sample2 = "word 111 sadas anything ORDER what whut yeap ASC nope ASC maybe ORDER yeah.";
String result2 = "word 111 sadas anything QQQ maybe ORDER yeah.";
// replaced "ORDER what whut yeap ASC nope ASC"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    s = s.replaceAll("(ORDER.*ASC)(?=.*?ORDER.*)", "QQQ");
```

Comment: what to do for remove last "ORDER" too?

Comment: @user2761286 State clearly in question what is the intended result. Currently you have ORDER in the output.

Comment: what if i want to remove that ORDER too?

Comment: s.replaceAll("(ORDER.*ORDER)", "QQQ"); will replace ORDER...ORDER with QQQ